# How can I export an Access query to Excel with a prompt for location and auto assigned properties?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to export an Access query to Excel with a prompt to save location, and would like it to auto assign a date and time stamp to a predetermined file name. This works great now if I don't want to pick a location each time:

```
Dim sNow As String
Dim sPath As String
Dim sName As String

    sNow = Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy-hhmmss")
    sPath = "C:\FULLPATH"
    sName = "NAME"

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QUERYNAME", acFormatXLS, sPath & sName & "_" & sNow & ".xls", True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()

    Dim sNow As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim fd As Object

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(2)

    sPath = "C:\FULLPATH"
    sNow = Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy-hhmmss")

    With fd
        .InitialFileName = sPath & "\" & sNow
        If .Show Then
            selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "no file selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With


    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QUERYNAME", acFormatXLS, fd.InitialFileName & "_" & sNow & ".xls", True
    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! it is a step in the right direction. Problem: when you hit cancel it still exports(does not cancel), and, the sPath is not changing the path--it opens the FD with the My Documents path.

```
Private Sub btnExportTRXBrowse_Click()
        Dim sNow As String
        Dim sPath As String
        Dim sName As String
        Dim fd As Object

        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(2)

        sPath = "C:\MYPATH\"
        sNow = Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy-hhmmss")
        sName = "TESTNAME_"

        With fd
            .InitialFileName = sPath & "\" & sName & sNow
            If .Show Then selectFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End With

        If fd.InitialFileName <> "" Then
          DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "QUERYNAME", acFormatXLS, fd.InitialFileName & "_" & sNow & ".xls", True
        End If
        Set fd = Nothing

    End Sub
```

Comment: When you hit cancel, Filename would be empty and it won't export - updated the code